# AS3 and cross-domain

Tags: actionscript-3

I think i'm a little confused. I'm loading an swf, located at `domainB.com/secondsubfolder`, from an swf located at `domainA.com/firstsubfolder`.

I always put the `crossdomain.xml` near the "loader" swf in `domainA.com/firstsubfolder`.

It seems to not work, except if I put the `crossdomain.xml` in the root of the loaded content, `domainB.com/crossdomain.xml`.

Did I always do it wrong, or is it because of some server setting? Using another domain for the loaded content, e.g. `domainB_beta.com/secondsubfolder` on another server just works as usual.

Where do I have to look to change these settings? Does it depend on server settings, or am I doing something wrong?

This is the loader actionscript code:

```
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.system.Security;

Security.allowDomain("domainB.com"); 
var context:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
context.securityDomain = SecurityDomain.currentDomain;

var loaderMain:Loader = new Loader();
loaderMain.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorHandler);
loaderMain.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorHandler);
loaderMain.load(new URLRequest('domainB/secondsubfolder/file.swf'),context);
addChild(loaderMain);

function errorHandler(event:ErrorEvent):void {
trace("errorHandler says: " + event);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on this example, your crossdomain file should be at http://domainb.com/crossdomain.xml. It looks like you have one there, but it's an old style. Perhaps try updating it to something like:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
    <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Also, you have Security.allowDomain set, but try adding Security.allowInsecureDomain as well. You aren't using HTTPS in your connection.

Finally, try running fiddler or charles to watch the network traffic. Look for the crossdomain.xml request and see what sort of response you are getting back. This could shed some additional light on the subject.

Comment: thnx ...ill try and post results!